# Fallout 4: bug in minutemen mission

Tags: fallout-4

I'm doing the minutemen missions in fallout 4 with hopes of unlocking the final mission. Unfortunately, I'm stuck in a mission where I'm supposed to eliminate raiders at olivia satellite station. I got the mission from Preston and it never activated. I toggle it on, no markings on the map, globally or locally. I nevertheless went there and cleaned the place up, but no luck. Also, it seems to be one of those missions that don't fail by themselves with time.

I'm playing on ps4 so no console in this case. Am I still able to unlock the final mission? What are conditions for unlocking it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant quest should be [Returning the Favor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Returning_the_Favor). First of all, try to speak with Blake Abernathy at the Abernathy farm just south-west of Sanctuary. He is the one giving details of the quest, namely to take revenge on the raiders for killing his daughter, but also to return her stolen locket. If you haven't returned the locket, this could be why the quest isn't finished.

It is found at the bottom of the Satellite station inside a toolbox, before the storage room filled with radroaches - including a radroach boss.

However, to unlock the final mission with the Minutemen, you only need to hold a certain amount of settlements for the Minutemen faction. You also need to be hostile with The Institute. (I believe you can also optionally have the Minutemen go to war against the Brotherhood if you are hostile to them.) All of this assuming you have finished all Minutemen quests such as reclaiming the castle and later defending it, and that you have found the Institute through the main story line quests.

Answer (score 1):

Go talk to the settlers at Abernathy Farm (go here for location http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Abernathy_farm) and talk to the people until they tell you to go to Olivia, then go back to the station and head to the very back where there is a red toolbox in front of a pair of double doors that leads to the last room. There is a locket in there that you need to return to Mr. Abernathy. Do all that and you should complete the quest.

Comment: How is this different from the already posted answer?

Answer (score -2):

Try loading an earlier save before talking to Preston. Or look for Olivia Sat Station location on google and go there.